# Log4net not working with windows service written by netcore

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, log4net

I have a windows service application which written by .net core.
In application, i using Log4net to log information to file but nothing is logged.
I tried to change application to console app, any thing is OK.

Please tell me how to fix this issue. Below is my logging config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="System_Appender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="System">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="System_Appender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="System_Appender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\System.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From your config file, I would expect the log file to be \windows\system32\logs\system.txt - Are you sure your service has permission to that folder? Also can you provide more details about how Log4net is initialised.

Comment: Here is how I initialize configurate for log4net.  ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
            _repositoryName = repository.Name;
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, new FileInfo(@"Logging.config"));

Comment: The only issue I can see is that your Logging.Config file would have to be located in the startup folder, which for Windows Services is usually %WinDir%\System32 or %WinDir%\SysWOW64 rather than the folder where your program is located.

Comment: The marked answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995219/net-core-worker-service-cannot-find-log4net-config-when-it-runs-as-a-windows-se solved for me!

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time messing with log4net .Net Core 3.1 running as a service. I will give some suggestions and code and configuration to review.

Running windows services with service account that has access to the logging and other databases doesn't log to the database
with log4net.

Running as a process but not as a service there was no problem with the log4net configuration. Only when running as a service
did the log4net not add logs to the database.

```
              public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

                    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                      .AddCommandLine(args)
                      .Build();

                    // run as a console or as a service, configure in appsettings.json
                    _runAsService = Configuration["RunAsService"].ConvertToBool();
                    _ServerCertThumbprint = Configuration["ConfigSettings:ServerCertThumbprint"];

                        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                }

                public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    // configure the app here.
                }).ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging(logging =>
                    {
                        logging.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                        logging.ClearProviders();
                        logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
                        // logging.AddConsole();
                        logging.AddDebug();
                        logging.AddEventLog();
                        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                        // logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true );
                    }).Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => options.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information);

                    services.AddSingleton(x);
                    services.AddSingleton<xxx>();
                    services.AddSingleton<xxx>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IXXX, XXX>();
                    services.AddSingleton<XXX>();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <log4net>
            <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
                <file value="logfile.log" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
                </layout>
            </appender>

            <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
                </layout>
            </appender>

            <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MicroKnights.Logging.AdoNetAppender, MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender">
                <bufferSize value="1" />

                <!--<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data" />-->
                <connectionType value="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5"/>
                <connectionStringName value="Log4Net" />
                <connectionStringFile value="appsettings.json" />

                <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log
```