# .Net Core Worker Service cannot find log4net.config when it runs as a windows service

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

I have these projects in my solution:

1. .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service
2. .Net Core 3.1 Class library - for configure the log4net

But my `log4net.config` file is inside my worker service project. When I'm debugging, it is logging to the file which is configured in the `log4net.config`.

But when I install the Worker Service as a Windows service, it doesn't log to the file.

And when I checked the `log4net.config` location it has these values:

1. When debugging: `D:\myrepos\webapicore\Development\Message.Consumer\log4net.config`
2. When running as a service: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\log4net.config`

So I believe, since the `log4net.config` is not available in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` it cannot do the logging.

UPDATE:
I'm using following code to retrieve the log4net.config

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

Any idea to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to the location of your service assembly before you initialise your logging config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed and configured log4net in a different class library.
So when I was getting the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` it was actually not giving the assembly location of where log4net has been installed.

Therefore I changed the this code part:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

Into:

```
var dirname = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}{1}", dirname, @"\log4net.config")));
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too with my .NET 5 `WorkerService`.

You could also use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, instead.

However, I then found out that you can simply create an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file (Add new item ...) and add

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

Just like before with .NET Framework 4.5, etc.